# Code is only saving one line of a text file to the array

Tags: java, arraylist, save

The code I have produced is meant to provide functionality of reading a text file line by line, saving each line into an array. It seems to read in each line correctly but when I use the printProps() method it only displays one...

Code is only saving one line of a text file to the array, what's wrong with my code?

```
/*reading in each line of text from text file and passing it to the processProperty() method.*/
Public void readProperties(String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        int i = 0;
        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null && !line.equals("")) {
            i++;
            processProperty(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("" + i + " properties read");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

/*Breaks up the line of text in order to save the value to an array (at this point it only saves one line to the array). org.newProp(newProp) passes the new property to the Organize class where it saves it to an array.

public void processProperty(String line) {
         org = new Organize();
        int id = nextPropertyID;
        nextPropertyID++;

        String[] parts = line.split(":");
        int propNo = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);            
        String postcode = parts[1];
        String type = parts[2];
        int bedrooms = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
        int rental = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);
        Landlord landlord = theLandlord;
        Tenant tenant = null;
        org.propUniqueCheck(id);
        propNoCheck(propNo, postcode);
        postcodeCheck(postcode,propNo);
        typeCheck(postcode, propNo, type);
        bedroomsCheck(bedrooms, postcode, propNo);
        yearCheck(propNo, postcode, year);
        System.out.println("Creating property " + id);

        Property newProp = new Property(id, propNo, postcode, type, bedrooms, year,
                rental, landlord, tenant);
        org.newProp(newProp);
        org.printProps();
    }

/*From here down it is the code to save the value to the array*/

public Organize() {
        props = new ArrayList<Property>();
        PTs = new ArrayList<PotentialTenant>(); 
        waitingList = new LinkedList<String>();
        //myList.add(new prop(Property.toString()));

    }
    public void newProp(Property p)
    {
        props.add(p);
    }
```

I have actively been seeking help in my seminar with this problem and I can't seem to find a solution, any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Where's the printProps method?

Comment: Without the printProps method we can not help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In processProperty you are instantiating a new `Organize` object. Therefore, each Property (which you create for each row) is ending up in a different ArrayList (as the first element).

One solution would be to instantiate one `Organize` object before you start your loop and then pass this into your processProperty method as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When one line in your text file is an empty String, your while-loop will break.

This is the right way to implement the loop:

```
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In processProperty you are instantiating a new Organize object. Therefore, each Property (which you create for each row) is ending up in a different ArrayList (as the first element).

One solution would be to instantiate one Organize object before you start your loop and then pass this into your processProperty method as a parameter.

```
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
// your code here
}
```